# Jquery get class "nodeId" value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to get value 117 out from the string. But failed to ...

When I do the following,

```
$(this)
```

I get "String" like this

```
"[Node: <span class='nodeId'>117</span>] <br>bla bla (bla/6)<br>Value: n.a."
```

Further derive from the following,

```
$(this).filter('.nodeId').html()
```

I get error...

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [Node: <span class='nodeId'>117</span>] <br>bla bla (bla/6)<br>Value: n.a.
```

Snippet as requested :

```
var onDeviceMarkerClick = function() {
        var currentNodeIdVal = null;
        var marker = this;
        var markerLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        var markerLng = marker.getPosition().lng();

        var checkStreetView = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat,markerLng);
        var svClient = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var checkaround = 50;
        svClient.getPanoramaByLocation(checkStreetView, checkaround, function (nearest) {
        if (nearest !== null){ 
            var nodeIdString = marker.title;
            var checkThisVal = $(nodeIdString).filter('.nodeId').html();
            console.log(checkThisVal); // Here I got the error

        //More to go
```

Anyone?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Please show a sample of your HTML in either a JSFiddle, or Stack Overflow code snippet. Your question is not very clear on how you are creating(?) or obtaining(?) the node.

Comment: What is `this`? [I can't reproduce the error](http://jsfiddle.net/en2hdeup/). Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi @Anoop Joshi and TrueBlueAussie please check above snippet. It is a google map, can be difficult to go JSFiddle.

Comment: @Vohuman it is Jquery 1.11.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML is not well-formed for jQuery (e.g. not starting with an `<>` element), you need to wrap it first (e.g. in a dummy `div` element)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vme0us9s/1/

```
var nodeIdString = marker.title;

// Create a new DIV and insert the content
var $div = $('<div>').html(nodeIdString);

var checkThisVal = $div.find('.nodeId').text();

alert(checkThisVal);  // Alerts 117
```

Comment: Let me try this out~ Appreciate and thanks a big bunch for the helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
var value = $('.nodeId').text();
```

Edit:
You can do this by:

```
var string = "<div>blah <span class='wew'>blah</span> sdf</div>";
console.log($(string).find('.wew').text());
```

note that string should be a valid html element.

Comment: If it wasn't valid html element is there a way?